# How to install a VSCode Extension from Source Code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

So i was using SFTP but the maintainer didnt update it anymore and it stopped working.

The community thankfully took over and fixed it here:
https://github.com/viperet/vscode-sftp-revived

I only know how to install a Extension by searching it in VSCode and press install - but have no clue how to do it with the source code.

I did Google & SOF research but wasnt successfull.

Can someone point me into the right direction ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a published vsix file to work with, for example if the source code has had recent changes that have not yet been published in a release, you can do the following to package the vsix and install it yourself:

0. Install node.js if you don't have it already, you can download binaries for your operating system here: https://nodejs.org/
1. Install the Visual Studio Code Extensions cli tool:

```
npm install -g @vscode/vsce
```

2. Clone the source code repository to your local machine
3. In your shell, change directory to the repository. Install dependencies as needed, for example using `npm install`
4. Run the following: `vsce package`. This will produce a .vsix file in your working directory.
5. In VS Code, open the extensions pane and in the menu, choose "Install from VSIX..."

[image: screenshot of vscode showing the install from vsix option]

6. Browse to the location of the new vsix file. After it installs, you'll be prompted to reload VS Code, choose to reload.

More reading: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#vsce

Answer (score 0):

Just download vsix from here and install: https://github.com/viperet/vscode-sftp-revived/releases

Anything is also just researching how to install a .vsix in vscode.